# Python vk_api добавление фото из сторонних ресурсов

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть массив, в котором хранятся ссылки на фото, которые в свою очередь необходимо прикрепить к посту в группе. Ниже приведен код, с помощью которого я пытался это сделать

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=my_login, password=my_password)
vk_session.auth()
destination = vk_session.method('photos.getUploadServer', {'group_id': group_id, 'album_id': album_id})
for i in range(len(photos_urls)):
    image = requests.get(photos_urls[i], stream=True)
    data = ('image' + str(i) + '.jpg', image.raw, image.headers['Content-Type'])
    meta = requests.post(destination['upload_url'], files={'photo': data}).json()
    photo = vk_session.method('photos.save', {'group_id': group_id, **meta})[0]
    vk_session.method('wall.post', {'owner_id': group_id, 'friends_only': 0, 'from_group': 1, 'attachments': photo['id'], 'signed': 0, 'mark_as_ads': 0, 'close_comments': 0})
```

Возникла ошибка - "vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [200] Access denied"
 Полазив по документации ВК, я пришел к выводу, что эта ошибка связана с недостаточностью прав пользователя, но

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login=my_login, password=my_password)
vk_session.auth()
```

я логинюсь на аккаунт владельца группы. Каким образом можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Я реализовал загрузку фото так — на вход подаю строки-ссылки на фотографии со стороннего ресурса, на выходе получаю строку типа *'photo123_123_123,photo123_123_123,...'*:

```py
import requests, vk_api

def upload(*args):
    session = requests.Session()
    photos = []
    for arg in args:
        image = session.get(arg, stream=True)
        photo = vk_upload.photo_messages(photos=image.raw)[0]
        photos.append('photo{}_{}_{}'.format(photo['owner_id'], photo['id'], photo['access_key']))
    return ','.join(photos)

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='very_very_very_long_token_which_not_for_you')
vk_upload = vk_api.upload.VkUpload(vk_session)
```

Но он не подойдёт под ваши рамки, т.к. вам необходима публикация загруженного фото на стене. Хотя можете попробовать оптимизировать под себя, если получится. Для менее трудоёмкой работы с кодом [воспользуйтесь модулем VKUpload, который находится в vk_api](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upload.html)

---

Ошибка 200 прописана в документации ВКонтакте — она связана с недостаточностью прав к фотографии, но проверить надо не логин-пароль, а правильность загружаемых данных.
[image: Трактовка ошибки 200 в документации ВКонтакте]

---

К тому же загружаете фото вы неправильно. Ознакомьтесь с порядком действий в документации ВКонтакте по гиперссылке — [Загрузка файлов › 2. Загрузка фотографий на стену](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83)

Пользуйтесь методом [photos.getWallUploadServer](https://vk.com/dev/photos.getWallUploadServer), а не photos.getUploadServer и [photos.saveWallPhoto](https://vk.com/dev/photos.saveWallPhoto), а не photos.save

---

По ходу действий дальше может возникнуть ещё одна ошибка, связанная с тем, что у вас отсутствует ключ доступа пользователя (но насчёт этого точно не уверен, попробуйте прогнать на всякий случай — может сработает):
[image: Описание метода wall.post]

Надеюсь, это был достаточно развёрнутый ответ, и он вам поможет)) Было бы неплохо, если бы вы оценили его)